# Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741502

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web-hosting

I am getting this error whenever I try to visit my site: www.adityaagroindustries.com

The error is as follows:

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -1073741502

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a memory issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2012/09/19/c-compiler-or-visual-basic-net-compilers-fail-with-error-code-1073741502-when-generating-assemblies-for-your-asp-net-site.aspx

Comment: The hosting provider asked me to download the entire application to my local machine and then recompile and then upload. Do you think that will help?

Comment: If the problem actually comes from memory exhaustion, I don't think it will help much, but you may want to try it anyway.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Sorry for late commenting but the error somehow disappeared from that site and now that same error is showing on another of my site: www.hapma.prismenterprizes.com. Both sites are hosted on the same hosting provider. I dont know whether I should  change my hosting provider or is there something wrong in my code. I am confused!!!

Comment: I check your site and it seems that your issue has been resolved. If you face this error again, please advise the full error message here.

Comment: @DouglasThomas  I have the same issue on my site can look my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673729/getting-error-the-compiler-failed-with-error-code-1073741502