# Getting Error: The compiler failed with error code -1073741502

Tags: asp.net, .net

Error:
http://s10.postimg.org/unr3dehax/Capture.png

I got this error in online server, It was worked fine when i upload yesterday and i modified some files then i uploaded everything again today ,after that its show like this.I m rushed to solve this, I searched in google ,i found something it is a permission issue. assist me to solve this.

Compiler detailed Error:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\assembly\dl3\7acac71e\06759a05_2c78d001\AjaxControlToolkit.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\assembly\dl3\d401b6f9\c19ff2cf_2b78d001\ExportPanel.DLL" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions.Design\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll" /out:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 /warnaserror-  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.4.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.5.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.3.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.1.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.10.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.11.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.9.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.13.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.14.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.15.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.16.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.17.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.18.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.7.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.12.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.2.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.19.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.8.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.0.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.20.cs" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\854e44cc\76541390\App_Code.2lvnktcq.6.cs"
```

Comment: what did you modify?

Comment: -1073741502 is 0xc0000142, which is `STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED`. This error can in turn be caused by many, many different things, since all it tells you is that loading a DLL failed. Try using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/bb896645) to see where API calls are failing.

Comment: @FelicePollano  Actually I have 2 modules in my project which is Admin and Customer Folder, I did changes on one report form  then i uploaded on Admin Folder,after that i tried to access that folder then it shows the Error, but the Customer Folder was  Worked fine, Then I thought i was missed something ,so i removed all files and i uploaded all files  again  after that Customer Folder also stopped working ,it shows the same error.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Is this about Folder permission issue ?